# Tomcat Failed to start with ssl - Did I miss anything?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have the following setup

1. purchased SSL certificate from ssl.com
2. Installed using

   ```
   keytool -import xxx
   ```
3. My Aliases are ...

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore /home/ubuntu/kykeystore.jks | grep Alias
   Enter keystore password:  password
   Alias name: goas
   Alias name: inter
   Alias name: root1
   Alias name: root2
   ```
4. My tomcat config is (server.xml)

   ```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443"
         />


      <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
              maxThreads="1000"  scheme="httpe" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
              sslEnabledProtocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
              keystoreFile="/home/ubuntu/kykeystore.jks" 
              keystorePass="password" 
             keyAlias="inter" />
   ```
5. Restarted the Tomcat:

   ```
   sudo service tomcat9 restart
   ```

I see this error in the catalina.out. Can you please help me.

```
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1055)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:589)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:612)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [inter] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:224)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1085)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1098)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:557)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [inter] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:248)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers(OpenSSLUtil.java:94)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: Run [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) against your `/home/ubuntu/kykeystore.jks` and verify that the key entry alias `inter` exists.  This will also verify that the password is valid.

Comment: You must import the signed certiicate into the keystore using the same alias you used when generating the keypair and the CSR.